# To say that "not p" holds, is the same as to say that p doesn't hold?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I know that this seems like a silly question, but I was deducing something and after finished I tried translating it into words. I don't know why but the doubt just sruck me as i was trying to make sense of what i was writing. Could any one please answer it and justfy it? thank you

Comment: not silly actually. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle

Comment: "Something", eh?  The answer depends on what you mean by that.  There are wffs $p$ such that neither $p$ nor $\neg p$ are tautologies.

Comment: This is the law of the excluded middle, for fans of Aristotelian logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your interpretation of "holds".

If, as is usually so, you mean "is true" as in classical logic, then "not P is true" and "P is not true" have the same meaning.

If you mean "is proven" or "is provable" as in constructive logic, then "not-P is proven" is not the same as "P is not proven".

Comment: I think bringing up constructive logic here is a bit misleading. If you have a formula $P$ of *classical* logic, and by "holds" you mean "is provable", then, as you say, "(not $P$) is proven" is not the same as "$P$ is not proven". Alternatively, you could talk about validity. "(not $P$) is valid" is not the same as "$P$ is not valid".

Comment: ok... then clarify please if this next senteces are valid (those were what i was trying to translate: 1) "To prove that for all x the statement P holds, is the same as to prove that it doesn't exist an x por which the statement p doesn't" and viceversa.  2) "To prove that not for all x the statement P holds, is the same as to prove that there exists an x for which the statement P doesn't hold". (Hold in this context means to be true or to hsappen) I'd be really gratefull

Comment: Yes, @AndrewM. , those are statements of the *quantifier duality* in *classic predicate logic*.  $$\forall x~P(x) \iff \neg \exists x~\neg P(x) \\ \neg \forall x~P(x) \iff \exists x~\neg P(x)$$